# Do I need to write unit tests for routing process?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm currently building a web application using Express. I would like to write unit tests for my web app.

Do I need to write unit tests for each routing process?
If I need to write a unit test for a routing process, please tell me why I need to write it.

Comment: Integration or functional tests maybe but you normally don't write unit tests for packages you use within your application.

Comment: I am sorry that my explanation is not good.

I am not talking about Express routing, about the routing process.

Comment: Your configuration of the routing would not be a unit test.

Comment: Well, each route has some purpose.  You will generally want to write a test to see that each route does what it's supposed to.  In the process of doing that, you will also be testing the routing since a given route won't do what it's supposed to if the routing didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is depends on level of confidence you looking to have for test coverage or requirement of high coverage level (>80% or something).
Usually business logic of routes is to call proper controller, so your test could be limited to mock controller and check (assert) that proper method of the controller is called.